# Why is pandas '==' different than '.eq()'

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
```

This is as expected

```
s == (3, 4)

0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

This is not

```
s.eq((3, 4))
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ValueError: Lengths must be equal
> ```

I was under the assumption they were the same. What is the difference between them?

---

***What does the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq) say?***

> Equivalent to series == other, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs.

This seems to imply that they should work the same, hence the confusion.

Comment: @piRSquared: It's better now that you have added some evidence of research effort into the post! At first you just said that you had assumed X thing and left it at that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you encounter is actually a special case that makes it easier to compare `pandas.Series` or `numpy.ndarray` with normal python constructs. The source code reads:

```
def flex_wrapper(self, other, level=None, fill_value=None, axis=0):
    # validate axis
    if axis is not None:
        self._get_axis_number(axis)
    if isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
        return self._binop(other, op, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
    elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, list, tuple)):
        if len(other) != len(self):
            # ---------------------------------------
            # you never reach the `==` path because you get into this.
            # ---------------------------------------
            raise ValueError('Lengths must be equal')  
        return self._binop(self._constructor(other, self.index), op,
                           level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
    else:
        if fill_value is not None:
            self = self.fillna(fill_value)

        return self._constructor(op(self, other),
                                 self.index).__finalize__(self)
```

You're hitting the `ValueError` because pandas assumes for `.eq` that you wanted the value converted to a `numpy.ndarray` or `pandas.Series` (*if you give it an array, list or tuple*) instead of actually comparing it to the `tuple`. For example if you have:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s.eq([1,2,3])
```

you wouldn't want it to compare each element to `[1,2,3]`.

The problem is that `object` arrays (as with `dtype=uint`) often slip through the cracks or are neglected on purpose. A simple `if self.dtype != 'object'` branch inside that method *could* resolve this issue. But maybe the developers had strong reasons to actually make this case different. I would advise to ask for clarification by posting on their [bug tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

---

You haven't asked how you can make it work correctly but for completness I'll include one possibility (according to the source code it seems likely you need to wrap it as `pandas.Series` yourself):

```
>>> s.eq(pd.Series([(1, 2)]))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` is an element-wise comparison that yields a vector of truth values, whereas `.eq` is a "those two iterables are equal", for which being of the same length is a requirement. Ayhan points to one exception: when you compare a pandas vector type using `.eq(scalar value)`, the scalar value is simply broadcast to a vector of the same size for comparison.

Comment: It broadcasts when you use a scalar actually: `s.eq(3)` for example.