# How do I fill null values while using pd.Series.__add__

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the two series `s1` and `s2`

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2], name='A')
s2 = pd.Series([1], name='A')
```

When I add them

```
s1 + s2

0    2.0
1    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I get `NaN` for index `1`
Instead I could do

```
s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)

0    2.0
1    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

However, I can't use `add`, I need to use `__add__`.  The problem is `pd.Series.__add__` doesn't have a `fill_value` parameter.

---

**Context**
So you understand why `__add__` is important to me

What I'm trying to do is subclass `pd.Series` and I want to add two members of my subclass with a plus sign `+` and have the default be to fill the missing values with `0`.  In order to use the `+` I have to define `__add__` in my subclass.  But I'd like to be able to leverage `pd.Series.__add__` and pass the appropriate parameter and value.  But as I've said, `pd.Series.__add__` doesn't have the `fill_value` parameter.

In contrast `pd.DataFrame.__add__` does have `fill_value`

---

**What I've Tried**
There is a `na_op` parameter that I suspect I can pass something to.  But I have no idea what.

```
s1.__add__(s2, na_op=0)

0    2.0
1    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

This is not what I want.  To be clear, I need to use `s1.__add__(s2, **kwargs)` where `kwargs` contains a keyword argument that will get me

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

---

This is the subclass code I've put together.  Hopefully it helps highlight what I'm trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

class SubDataFrame(pd.Series):

    _metadata = ['date']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubDataFrame

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.date = pd.to_datetime(kwargs.pop('date', pd.datetime.now().date()))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other, *args, **kwargs):
#         kwargs.setdefault('fill_value', 0);
        return super().__add__(other, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Couldn't you do something like use the add function from the super class and use fillna afterwards? Or is the problem that your add function has the wrong signature?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I'm trying to subclass `pd.Series`.  I could define my `__add__` method to accomplish this in a way that you suggested.  However, I'm trying to minimize augmentation. If `+` uses `__add__` I want to pass all my arguments through `__add__`.  Ultimately, I've asked my question accordingly with a strict limitation that the solution must use `pd.Series.__add__`

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, I just scanned the [series sources](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/series.py). There no __add__ function is defined. I also skimmed through the parents but didn't find the __add__ function. Do we use the numpy function here? Could you provide a link to the sources of ``Series.__add__` and `DataFrame.__add__`?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 if you do `print s1.__add__`, it says `Series.wrapper`. So the function is appended by a wrapper somewhere within the code somewhere

Comment: @piRSquared if you are bold enough, then you may contemplate monkey-patching the `pd.Series.__add__` method. If that sounds like something you want to do, take a look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jay3080fwt5jfu/monkey_patching_pandas_series.py?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure I follow, but are you just trying to override the `__add__` method?   Excluding the [other stuff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) you need to do to properly subclass pandas objects, roughly:

```
class PiR2Series(pd.Series):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PiR2Series, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.add(other, fill_value=0)
```

Then you can do:

```
s1 = PiR2Series([1, 2], name='A')
s2 = PiR2Series([1], name='A')

s1 + s2

0    2.0
1    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Disclaimer: I haven't really done much subclassing of pandas objects, so I can't guarantee that the above is the proper thing to do.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to overload `__add__`.  However, I don't want to use `self.add` to do it.  I want to use `super().__add__`.  This way I guarantee the behavior is identical to what it should be.  You see, I'm suspicious that `add` and `__add__` are **not** the same.  I know I have a question about this.  I'm looking it up now.

Comment: Per the docs on [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):  "Equivalent to `series + other`, but with support to substitute a `fill_value` for missing data in one of the inputs."

Comment: I found it!... This was the source of my hesitation.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/41410178/2336654 This is not `add` though and my hesitation may be unfounded.

Answer (score -2):

To fill in `NaN`s with a value, use `df.fillna(<value>)`.

Comment: This does not answer the question!  I need to get the solution through the `__add__` method.  I stated that pretty clearly