# Why isn't pandas logical operator aligning on the index like it should?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple setup:

```
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=list('abc'))
y = pd.Series([2, 3, 3], index=list('bca'))

x

a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64

y

b    2
c    3
a    3
dtype: int64
```

As you can see, the indexes are the same, just in a different order.

Now, consider a simple logical comparison using the equality (`==`) operator:

```
x == y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

This throws a `ValueError`, most likely because the indexes do not match. On the other hand, calling the equivalent `eq` operator works:

```
x.eq(y)

a    False
b     True
c     True
dtype: bool
```

OTOH, the operator method works given `y` is first reordered...

```
x == y.reindex_like(x)

a    False
b     True
c     True
dtype: bool
```

My understanding was that the function and operator comparison should do the same thing, all other things equal. What is `eq` doing that the operator comparison doesn't?

Comment: Different issue, but just for network connectedness: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410178/why-is-pandas-different-than-eq

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Viewing the whole traceback for a Series comparison with mismatched indexes, particularly focusing on the exception message:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=list('abc'))
In [3]: y = pd.Series([2, 3, 3], index=list('bca'))
In [4]: x == y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-73b2790c1e5e> in <module>()
----> 1 x == y
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1188 
   1189         elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(othe
r):
-> 1190             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
   1191                              "Series objects")
   1192 
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

we see that this is a deliberate implementation decision. Also, this is not unique to Series objects - DataFrames raise a similar error.

Digging through the Git blame for the relevant lines eventually turns up some relevant commits and issue tracker threads. For example, `Series.__eq__` used to completely ignore the RHS's index, and in a [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1134#issuecomment-5347816) on a bug report about that behavior, Pandas author Wes McKinney says the following:

> This is actually a feature / deliberate choice and not a bug-- it's
>   related to [#652](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/652). Back in January I changed the comparison methods to
>   do auto-alignment, but found that it led to a large amount of bugs /
>   breakage for users and, in particular, many NumPy functions (which
>   regularly do things like `arr[1:] == arr[:-1]`; example: `np.unique`)
>   stopped working.
>
> This gets back to the issue that Series isn't quite ndarray-like
>   enough and should probably not be a subclass of ndarray.
>
> So, I haven't got a good answer for you except for that;
>   auto-alignment would be ideal but I don't think I can do it unless I
>   make Series not a subclass of ndarray. I think this is probably a good
>   idea but not likely to happen until 0.9 or 0.10 (several months down
>   the road).

This was then [changed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/5152cdd77ba4799a276d2716535255c3301e9741) to the current behavior in pandas 0.19.0. Quoting the ["what's new" page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#series-operators-for-different-indexes):

> Following Series operators have been changed to make all operators
>   consistent, including DataFrame ([GH1134](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134), [GH4581](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4581),
>   [GH13538](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13538))
>
> - Series comparison operators now raise ValueError when index are different.
> - Series logical operators align both index of left and right hand side.

This made the Series behavior match that of DataFrame, which already rejected mismatched indices in comparisons.

In summary, making the comparison operators align indices automatically turned out to break too much stuff, so this was the best alternative.

Comment: Great answer.  There should be an investigator badge.  Designed for answers like this where the answer author clearly has taken the time to research, read the code, dig through Git to find logical explanations. +1

Answer (score 8):

One thing I love about python is that you can peak into source code of almost anything. And from `pd.Series.eq` source code, it calls:

```
def flex_wrapper(self, other, level=None, fill_value=None, axis=0):
    # other stuff
    # ...

    if isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
        return self._binop(other, op, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
```

and go on to `pd.Series._binop`:

```
def _binop(self, other, func, level=None, fill_value=None):

    # other stuff
    # ...
    if not self.index.equals(other.index):
        this, other = self.align(other, level=level, join='outer',
                                 copy=False)
        new_index = this.index
```

That means the `eq` operator aligns the two series before comparison (which, apparently, the normal operator `==` does not).

Answer (score 5):

Back to 2012 , when we do not have `eq` , `ne` and `gt` , `pandas` have the problem : disorder `Series` will return the unexpected output with logic (`>,<,==,!=`) , so they doing with a fix (new function added, `gt`,`ge`,`ne`..)

GitHub Ticket [reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1134)